# Object getting sorted inside NamedNodeMap

Tags: java, dom, w3c

To get attributes detail for following XML element

```
<catalog e="1" b="2" a="0">
```

I use `NamedNodeMap` to get attribute, It is sorting the attributes as

> a = 0,
>    b = 2,
>    e = 1

How can I print it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute ordering is not a feature of [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) which [the Java type implements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html). See the [W3C documentation for NamedNodeMap](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922):

> `NamedNodeMap`s are not maintained in any particular order. Objects contained in an object implementing `NamedNodeMap` may also be accessed by an ordinal index, but this is simply to allow convenient enumeration of the contents of a `NamedNodeMap`, and does not imply that the DOM specifies an order to these Nodes.

If you require this, the standard DOM is not what you are looking for.